# RegEx for URL validation - Javascript ( AngularJs )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need following URL should be returned as true

- http://some.url
- http://other.some.url
- http://other.some.url/page/1
- http://some.url/page/1
- https://some.url
- https://other.some.url
- https://some.url/page/1
- other.some.url
- some.url
- some.url/page/1

Following url should be returned as false

- http://some.url/test?id=something
- http://some.url/test?id=something&value=somethingelse
- somerandomvalue

This is regex I tried so far `/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/`. Im using this inside angular form input ng-patter

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: looks like you are categorizing get request data as false. Couldn't you just search for "?"

Comment: try this pattern maybe it'll fit you:  `/([a-z0-9_\-]{1,5}:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}):([a-z0-9_\-]{1,})\@)?((www\.)|([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}\.)+)?([a-z0-9_\-]{3,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})(\/([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}\/)+)?([a-z0-9_\-]{1,})?(\.[a-z]{2,})?(([\?\&][a-z0-9_\-]{1,}\=[a-z0-9_\-]{1,})+)?/gi`

Comment: @BloomBlack anything comes after ? is invalid URL for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression

/^((?:http://)|(?:https://))(www.)?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{3})|(?:\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}(?::\d+)?))([/a-zA-Z0-9.]*)$/gm

```
function isUrlValid(userInput) {
    var res = userInput.match(/^((?:http:\/\/)|(?:https:\/\/))(www.)?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{3})|(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?::\d+)?))([\/a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)$/gm);
    if(res == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
 }
```

Comment: something is wrong with regex. it is throwing error